# How to reopen connection in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have app in SpringBoot with JPA.
When I lost connection my app send me error:

> WARN 6812 --- [io-8080-exec-42] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006 
>   ERROR 6812 --- [io-8080-exec-42] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : IO Error: Socket read timed
>   out

After estabilishin connection I can't use my EntityManager, because I get:

> WARN 6812 --- [io-8080-exec-50] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 08003 
>   ERROR 6812 --- [io-8080-exec-50] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : Closed Connection

My connection properties:

> spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver 
>   spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@...:..:.. 
>   spring.datasource.username=... 
>   spring.datasource.password=... 
>   spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true 
>   spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true 
>   spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1;

What should I do to reconnect that DB connection?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an external connection pool, such as [HikariCP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html), since Spring Boot will automatically detect and use it:

> If HikariCP is available we will use it.

If your using a JDBC4 Driver, the connection pool will validate the connection before handing it to you. If you are using an older driver you need to set this property:

> **connectionTestQuery**
>
> If your driver supports JDBC4 we strongly recommend not setting this
>   property. This is for "legacy" databases that do not support the JDBC4
>   Connection.isValid() API. This is the query that will be executed just
>   before a connection is given to you from the pool to validate that the
>   connection to the database is still alive. Again, try running the pool
>   without this property, HikariCP will log an error if your driver is
>   not JDBC4 compliant to let you know. Default: none

Comment: from doc: "If you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa ‘starter POMs’ you will automatically get a dependency to tomcat-jdbc." the question now if @Son used starter POM or not.

Comment: Yes, I have both jdbc and data-jdbc.
It's any other option to open new connection after disconnect?